# .Net Maui / Xamarin Collectionview filtering with searchbar - how to clear memory?

Tags: xamarin, search, memory, collectionview, maui

I have been trying to figure out why my app is consuming so much memory, I have a searchbar that is used to filter by name property of my ObservableCollection and when the search contents change a lot from "Test" to a blank string "" the memory continually increases. I know not everyone will be changing the search field 1000x times but that memory never gets freed up and there must be a reason? I've been looking at the memory usage in the emulator Pixel 5 under running services in the dev options -- I'm using Visual studio community 2022 preview 6.

---

The top image is before using search and the bottom is after 500X times changing searchbar text from "Test" to "" (I used a loop 500X)

[image: Before using search]

[image: After using search]

---

Here is the code:

```
async void Item_Search(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var currentSearchText = e.NewTextValue.ToLowerInvariant();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(currentSearchText))
        {
            currentSearchText = string.Empty;
        }
        var filteredItems = ItemListSource.Where(value => value.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(currentSearchText)).ToList();
                 
        foreach (var value in ItemListSource)
        {
            if (!filteredItems.Contains(value))
            {
                ItemList.Remove(value);
            }
            else if (!ItemList.Contains(value))
            {
                ItemList.Add(value);
            }
        }
        

    }
```

The itemlistsource is an observablecollection that is set in onappearing from a database pull -- await App.Database.GetItems(); ItemList is the ObservableCollection that gets displayed which is initially set equal to the itemlistsource also in onappearing.

The model is:

```
public class Item
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int id { get; set; }
        private string name;
        public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }
        private string notes;
        public string Notes { get { return notes; } set { notes = value; } }
        private string category;
        public string Category { get { return category; } set { category = value; } }
        
    }
```

}

Comment: Perhaps GC isn't getting a chance to free stuff. Is the loop in an `async` method? If so, what happens if you add `await Task.Delay(100);` inside the loop? That slows the updates down to 10 per second. Lets other code run. Also, as a test, might explicitly call `GC.Collect/GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers` periodically. `int i = 0;` then in loop `i++; if (i % 50 == 0) { GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); }` would call every 5 seconds. (NOTE: I wouldn't do that in production - forcing GC in any GC system can be counter-productive - let GC manage itself.)